Is there a way to perform a map on a single digit similar to an array?
const emptyRow = 3;

How can I map on this if it's a number and not an array?
Similar to using map on an array but instead on a number.
something like:
    emptyRow.map(el => {
return (
<div>place items here</div>
)
})

The purpose to this is that I would like to create divs dynamically based on the number of emptyRows.

What do you expect to map from the number 3?

I just updated sorry, I should have updated that before @ScottZ

Still doesn't explain what mapping a number would do. Do you want 3 divs?

@tkausl sorry I apologize, yes I'd like 3 rows.  It should be dynamic so if the number is set to 5 then it would create 5 divs.

String.repeat?

You need a loop, not a mapping. Read about Array.prototype.map() and about loops in the JavaScript documentation.

`Array.from({length: emptyRow}, () => (
place items here
))`
This question is similar to: How can I render repeating React elements?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Not pretty, but it's simple and it works.
const emptyRows = 3;
Array(emptyRows).fill(0).map(el => {
  return (
    <div>place items here</div>
  )
})


Doesn't really work that way... you seem like maybe you're confusing map with repeat, which I believe only works on strings.
What you can do is create a range. Javascript doesn't have a native range function, but you can write it pretty easily:


    const range = (length, offset = 0) => Array.from({length}, (_, n) => n + offset);

    // logs: [ "<div/>", "<div/>", "<div/>" ]
    console.log(range(3).map(() => `<div/>`));

    // logs [ "<div key='0' />", "<div key='1' />", "<div key='2' />" ]
    console.log(range(3).map((i) => `<div key='${i}'/>`));

    // logs: [ "<div key='2'/>", "<div key='3'/>", "<div key='4'/>" ]
    console.log(range(3, 2).map((i) => `<div key='${i}'/>`));



